# A Lagrange Mean Value Theorem question

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is differentiable in the interval $[-2,5]$, $f(-2)=f(5)=0,f(0)<0$.
Let us prove: $\exists$ $\xi\in[-2,5]$, $f'(\xi)>0$.

I know the condition can use Lagrange Mean Value Theorem.

$f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable over $[−2,5]$,
$\xi\in (-2,5)$, $f'(\xi)=
\frac{f\left( 5 \right) -f\left( -2 \right)}{5-\left( -2 \right)}=0
$, but how to next step and how to use the condition $f(0)<0$.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it should use mean value theorem. $f(-2)-f(0)=-2f'(\xi_{1})$ and $f(5)-f(0)=5f'(\xi_{2})$, by condition $f'(\xi_{1})<0$ and $f'(\xi_{2})>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the MVT on $[0,5]$ to get a point where the derivative equals $-f(0)/5 > 0$.

Comment: thanks,i understand it